# Dialog from BackgroundWorker waiting for user input

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

Can I open Dialog from BackgroundWorker and pause it until user decides?

```
MyWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
MyWorker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(CopyWorker_DoWork);
MyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

private void MyWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int i=0;
    while ((i) < collection.Count())
    {
       cListEntry item = collection[i];
       if (item.conflicted ==true) {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                var dialog = new WindowConflict();
                //Open dialog and wait for user action
                if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    item.level = dialog.Response;
                }
```

Comment: With .Invoke instead of .BeginInvoke it'll proably work. But you shouldn't want to do this.

Comment: What's a `WindowConflict`?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I don't think so. The only difference is the `Invoke` is `Post` when `BeginInvoke` is `Send` but both to the Dispatcher's synchronization context.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - Milo wants the Bgw to wait for the outcome. That's the difference.

Comment: A user dialog on on BackgroundWorker?   Why?

Comment: You are supposed to use async/await in all cases to avoid such scenarios. Creating UI elements (such as dialogs) in a thread other than the main thread, should be avoided. There are far too many ways to bring async/await down to legacy .NET versions, so there is no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use invoke instead of begininvoke, begininvoke allows the task to continue running but you want it to wait.